# Eulers Phi of Huge numbers

Tags: c++, cryptography, eulers-number

Its easy to compute eulers phi of small numbers, there are even many online sites that offer such functions. But what when the numbers are really huge, I mean like 2^128? How can I compute an eulers phi function of such high number? Can I use my desktop pc for this?

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ Big Number Library" and "C++ Multiprecision Library".

Comment: As far as using your desktop PC goes, depends on the memory capacity.  Huge numbers require more memory than standard ones.  Also, depends on how much data you have and how much processing needs to be performed.  This also depends on the tools.  If your PC has the tools on it to develop software, you can use your PC.

Comment: Let's all hope that you won't find a desktop solution any time soon.

Comment: Numbers the size of 2^128 are easily factorable these days; Morrison and Brillhart famously factored 2^128+1 = 59649589127497217 * 5704689200685129054721 in the late 1960s. Such numbers are in reach of a desktop pc today, and can be factored in seconds. But really large numbers, like the 2048-bit semi-primes that are commonly used in cryptography, still cannot be factored.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the prime factors, then yes.  But in general you can't do it efficiently, at least not in a way anyone knows of.  If we could compute the totient function in general, then we could get it for n = pq, where p and q are primes, which would be (p-1)(q-1).  So n - phi(n) = p + q - 1, and we then know p+q = c.  Then (p+q)^2 = c^2, so p^2 + q^2 = c^2 - 2n.  But then (p-q)^2 = p^2 + q^2 - 2pq = c^2 - 4n.  So we know p+q and p-q, from which we can get p and q.

This would break [RSA encryption](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm))

Comment: what when I have 3 primes? I got 2^290 *29 *53 = my number

Comment: @Sick654 You can directly use [Euler's product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function), with only 3 distinct primes it is very easy.